# Skipping a column/row in a table based on its dimensions using VBA in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

So I'm creating a label making macro on Word that will copy and paste one label into a specified amount of labels. The problem is that the table is set up so that there is 1 blank column between each label, and 1 blank row between each row of labels. There are 7 labels in each row, 17 in each column. The place where the label is created has a height of 0.5" and width of 0.94". The columns in-between have a 0.13" width, and the rows in-between have a 0.13" height. So I wrote my code based on the cell dimensions. But, its not working. It doesn't give an error, but it pastes into every cell instead of skipping the ones that are too small. A picture of the label template is attached. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, so any insight would be appreciated!

```
Sub labels()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

    For i = 1 To labels2.TextBox3.Value
        If tbl.Rows.Height < 0.5 And tbl.Columns.Width < 0.9 Then
            Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
        Else
            Selection.Paste
            Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you know you always need to skip a column between each label and a row between each row you can do something like this:

```
Sub labels()

    Dim numLabels As Long, i As Long

    Dim tbl As Table, rw As Long, c As Long
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

    numLabels = 10
    i = 0

    For rw = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count Step 2
        For c = 1 To tbl.Columns.Count Step 2
            tbl.Cell(rw, c).Range.Paste
            i = i + 1
            If i = numLabels Then GoTo done
        Next c
    Next rw

done:
    MsgBox "Labels Created"
End Sub
```